# Numbers $m,n$, such that $a^m+ab+b^n$ is always composite

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Are there integers $m,n\ge 2$, such that $$a^m+ab+b^n$$ is composite for all
 integers $a,b\ge 2$ ?

I checked the pairs with $2\le m\le 100$ and $2\le n\le 100$ and always found a prime
 of the form $a^m+ab+b^n\ ,\ a,b\ge 2$

Due to symmetry, $m\le n$ can be assumed.

Comment: Fix any $m,n$.  There will never be a prime $p$ that always divides $a^m + ab + b^n$ (because one could take $a\equiv 0$, $b\equiv 1$).  Thus the only practical hope for finding an example lies in finding an irreducible $a^m + ab + b^n$, turning this into a question about polynomials...

Comment: On the converse side, there is pretty much no hope of proving (at the current state of the art) that all values of $m,n$ work.  It was a major breakthrough in sieve theory to be able to detect primes in sets as thin as $\{a^2 + b^4\}$ and $\{a^3 + 2b^3\}$, so getting $m,n$ arbitrarily high seems quite out of reach.